# Telegram icon in Modern CV

Tags: moderncv, fontawesome

I have a version of my CV which compiles successfully and includes lots of modifications such as a second address line, inclusion of several icons from Font Awesome such as Whatsapp and Skype, etc. However, my attempts to include a Telegram icon don't seem to work. In the "\addresstwo" line (line #87) I can show a MWE of Whatsapp working just fine. When I try to change it to the line just below, I compile with error messages and no icon. I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate SP1.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\moderncvicons{awesome}                     

%Other packages
\usepackage{verbatim}    %allows for blocks of comments
%\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{stackengine}  %allows for signiture to be added to letter.


% Code for a second address in the info block:
\makeatletter

\RenewDocumentCommand{\address}{mG{}G{}G{}}{\def\@addressstreet{#1}\def\@addresscity{#2}\def\@addresscountry{#3}\def\@addressmobilephone{#4}}

\newcommand*{\addresstwo}[4]{\def\@addressstreettwo{#1}\def\@addresscitytwo{#2}\def\@addresscountrytwo{#3}\def\@addressmobilephonetwo{#4}}
\renewcommand*{\makecvfoot}{%
  \recomputecvfootlengths{}%
  \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyfoot[c]{%
      \parbox[b]{\footwidth}{%
        \centering%
        \color{color2}\addressfont%
        \vspace{\baselineskip}% forces a white line to ensure space between main text and footer (as footer height can't be known in advance)
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\addtofoot[]{\addresssymbol\@addressstreet}%
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\addtofoot[~--~]{\@addresscity}}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and \addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\addtofoot[~--~]{\@addresscountry}}%
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addressmobilephone}{}}{}{\addtofoot[~--~]{\@addressmobilephone}}%
        %\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreettwo}}{}{\addtofoot[]{\addresssymbol\@addressstreettwo}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreettwo}}{\flushfoot\@firstfootelementtrue\\}{\flushfoot\\\addtofoot[]{\addresssymbol\@addressstreettwo}%
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscitytwo}{}}{}{\addtofoot[~--~]{\@addresscitytwo}}%
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountrytwo}{}}{}{\addtofoot[~--~]{\@addresscountrytwo}}%
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addressmobilephonetwo}{}}{}{\addtofoot[~--~]{\@addressmobilephonetwo}}%
          \flushfoot\@firstfootelementtrue\\}}%
        \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
          \addtofoot{\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\addtofoot{\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\addtofoot{\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}}%
        \collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
          \addtofoot{\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\addtofoot{\@extrainfo}}%
        \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\footboxwidth=0pt}}{}{\flushfoot}% the lengthtest is required to avoid flushing an empty footer, which could cause a blank line due to the \\ after the address, if no other personal info is used
        }}}%
  \pagestyle{plain}}


% Code for a skype symbol in the info block:
\newcommand*{\skypesocialsymbol}{{\color{cyan!65!white}\faSkype}}
\newcommand*{\tangerinesocialsymbol}{{\includegraphics[height=.7\baselineskip]{tangerine}}}
\collectionadd[skype]{socials}{ SkypeAddress}


\renewcommand*{\recomputefootlengths}{%
  \setlength{\footwidth}{1.0\textwidth}}

\renewcommand*{\makeletterclosing}{
  \@closing\\[1em]%
  {\bfseries \@firstname~\@lastname}%
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@enclosure}}{}{%
    \\[3em]%
    {\color{color2}\itshape\enclname: \@enclosure}}}

\makeatother

% Code to change the symbols used in the info block:
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\mobilephonesymbol}   {{\Large{\faMobile}}~\normalsize}
\renewcommand*{\emailsymbol}         {{\color{red!85!black}{\small\faEnvelopeO}~}}         % alternative: \faInbox
\renewcommand*{\linkedinsocialsymbol}{{\color{cyan!55!black}\small\faLinkedin}~}           % alternative: \faLinkedinSquare
\renewcommand*{\twittersocialsymbol} {{\color{cyan!75!white}\small\faTwitter}~}            % alternative: \faTwitterSquare
\renewcommand*{\githubsocialsymbol}  {{\color{black}\faGithubSquare}~}
\makeatother

\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{0.22,0.45,0.70}% light blue

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.8, left=1.6cm, right=1.7cm]{geometry}
% personal data
\name{First}{Last Name}
\title{Job Title}
\address{Street Address 1}{Zip}{Country}{{ \ \Large{\faMobile}}~+00~(0)~000~00~0000}
\addresstwo{Street Address 1}{Zip}{Country}{{ \ \Large{\faMobile}} \ {\color{green!60!black}\faWhatsapp } ~+0~(000)~000~0000}
%\addresstwo{Street Address 1}{Zip}{Country}{{ \ \Large{\faMobile}} \ {\color{green!60!black}\faTelegram } ~+0~(000)~000~0000}

\email{MyEmail@email.com}                
\social[linkedin]{My Name}                % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\social[twitter]{My Name}                       % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\social[github]{My Name}                        % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted

% bibliography adjustements (only useful if you make citations in your resume, or print a list of publications using BibTeX)
%   to show numerical labels in the bibliography (default is to show no labels)
\makeatletter\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}\makeatother
%   to redefine the bibliography heading string ("Publications")
%\renewcommand{\refname}{Articles}

% bibliography with mutiple entries
%\usepackage{multibib}
%\newcites{book,misc}{{Books},{Others}}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

%-----       resume       ---------------------------------------------------------
\makecvtitle

%\newpage
\section{Resume Section}
\cventry{2000--present}{Job Title}{}{City, Country}{}{
Project details:%
    \begin{itemize}%
        \item Responsibilities
    \end{itemize}%
}
\end{document}
```

I'm guessing this has something to do with my version of FontAwesome, but I've gone into Miktex 2.9 and run the "Maintenance (Admin)/Miktex Update (Admin)" program as well as "/MiKTeX Package Manager (Admin)" updates and haven't been able to get it working correctly. I'm not totally sure how all these package managers update so I might be doing something wrong. Any advice most welcome.

Comment: If you really want to use the telegram icon from fontawesome, your best bet is to use fontspec+XeLaTeX: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/345677/117534

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update 2018:**

With the new `fontawesome5` package you can now directly use `\faTelegram`:

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\begin{document}

\faTelegram

\end{document}
```

---

**Before 2018:**

The package `fontawesome` does not contain a command `\faTelegram`. An overview of the available symbols can be found in the package documentation: http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/fontawesome/doc/fontawesome.pdf

In case you are satisfied with a paper aeroplane instead:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\moderncvicons{awesome}                     

%Other packages
\usepackage{verbatim}    %allows for blocks of comments
%\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{stackengine}  %allows for signiture to be added to letter.


% Code for a second address in the info block:
\makeatletter

\RenewDocumentCommand{\address}{mG{}G{}G{}}{\def\@addressstreet{#1}\def\@addresscity{#2}\def\@addresscountry{#3}\def\@addressmobilephone{#4}}

\newcommand*{\addresstwo}[4]{\def\@addressstreettwo{#1}\def\@addresscitytwo{#2}\def\@addresscountrytwo{#3}\def\@addressmobilephonetwo{#4}}
\renewcommand*{\makecvfoot}{%
  \recomputecvfootlengths{}%
  \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyfoot[c]{%
      \parbox[b]{\footwidth}{%
        \centering%
        \color{color2}\addressfont%
        \vspace{\baselineskip}% forces a white line to ensure space between main text and footer (as footer height can't be known in advance)
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\addtofoot[]{\addresssymbol\@addressstreet}%
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\addtofoot[~--~]{\@addresscity}}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and \addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\addtofoot[~--~]{\@addresscountry}}%
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addressmobilephone}{}}{}{\addtofoot[~--~]{\@addressmobilephone}}%
        %\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreettwo}}{}{\addtofoot[]{\addresssymbol\@addressstreettwo}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreettwo}}{\flushfoot\@firstfootelementtrue\\}{\flushfoot\\\addtofoot[]{\addresssymbol\@addressstreettwo}%
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscitytwo}{}}{}{\addtofoot[~--~]{\@addresscitytwo}}%
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountrytwo}{}}{}{\addtofoot[~--~]{\@addresscountrytwo}}%
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addressmobilephonetwo}{}}{}{\addtofoot[~--~]{\@addressmobilephonetwo}}%
          \flushfoot\@firstfootelementtrue\\}}%
        \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
          \addtofoot{\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\addtofoot{\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\addtofoot{\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}}%
        \collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
          \addtofoot{\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\addtofoot{\@extrainfo}}%
        \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\footboxwidth=0pt}}{}{\flushfoot}% the lengthtest is required to avoid flushing an empty footer, which could cause a blank line due to the \\ after the address, if no other personal info is used
        }}}%
  \pagestyle{plain}}


% Code for a skype symbol in the info block:
\newcommand*{\skypesocialsymbol}{{\color{cyan!65!white}\faSkype}}
\newcommand*{\tangerinesocialsymbol}{{\includegraphics[height=.7\baselineskip]{tangerine}}}
\collectionadd[skype]{socials}{ SkypeAddress}


\renewcommand*{\recomputefootlengths}{%
  \setlength{\footwidth}{1.0\textwidth}}

\renewcommand*{\makeletterclosing}{
  \@closing\\[1em]%
  {\bfseries \@firstname~\@lastname}%
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@enclosure}}{}{%
    \\[3em]%
    {\color{color2}\itshape\enclname: \@enclosure}}}

\makeatother

% Code to change the symbols used in the info block:
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\mobilephonesymbol}   {{\Large{\faMobile}}~\normalsize}
\renewcommand*{\emailsymbol}         {{\color{red!85!black}{\small\faEnvelopeO}~}}         % alternative: \faInbox
\renewcommand*{\linkedinsocialsymbol}{{\color{cyan!55!black}\small\faLinkedin}~}           % alternative: \faLinkedinSquare
\renewcommand*{\twittersocialsymbol} {{\color{cyan!75!white}\small\faTwitter}~}            % alternative: \faTwitterSquare
\renewcommand*{\githubsocialsymbol}  {{\color{black}\faGithubSquare}~}
\makeatother

\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{0.22,0.45,0.70}% light blue

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.8, left=1.6cm, right=1.7cm]{geometry}
% personal data
\name{First}{Last Name}
\title{Job Title}
\address{Street Address 1}{Zip}{Country}{{ \ \Large{\faMobile}}~+00~(0)~000~00~0000}
%\addresstwo{Street Address 1}{Zip}{Country}{{ \ \Large{\faMobile}} \ {\color{green!60!black}\faWhatsapp } ~+0~(000)~000~0000}
\addresstwo{Street Address 1}{Zip}{Country}{{ \ \Large{\faMobile}} \ {\color{green!60!black}\faPaperPlaneO } ~+0~(000)~000~0000}

\email{MyEmail@email.com}                
\social[linkedin]{My Name}                % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\social[twitter]{My Name}                       % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\social[github]{My Name}                        % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted

% bibliography adjustements (only useful if you make citations in your resume, or print a list of publications using BibTeX)
%   to show numerical labels in the bibliography (default is to show no labels)
\makeatletter\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}\makeatother
%   to redefine the bibliography heading string ("Publications")
%\renewcommand{\refname}{Articles}

% bibliography with mutiple entries
%\usepackage{multibib}
%\newcites{book,misc}{{Books},{Others}}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

%-----       resume       ---------------------------------------------------------
\makecvtitle

%\newpage
\section{Resume Section}
\cventry{2000--present}{Job Title}{}{City, Country}{}{
Project details:%
    \begin{itemize}%
        \item Responsibilities
    \end{itemize}%
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is that because the package isn't up-to-date? It appears on their website (http://fontawesome.io/icon/telegram/)  which is why I thought I could include it.

Comment: @Michael This is something only the package authors can know